# responding to WatchOS 10 workout widget play/pause button in third party app

Tags: swiftui, widget, apple-watch, watchos, healthkit

I've been searching Apple's documentation (and the rest of the web) for this and I haven't found a mention. Also looked through `HKWorkoutSession.h` for anything in WatchOS 10 that might be related. I have a workout app for Apple Watch. It appears that using HKWorkoutSession automatically activates Apple's own stack widget in WatchOS 10, showing elapsed workout time and giving the user a play/pause button. However, it doesn't appear to give you automatic access to the play/pause button event. I've set breakpoints in the `.onOpenURL(perform: { url in` method I have implemented for my own widget. I also set a breakpoint in

```
func workoutSession(_ workoutSession: HKWorkoutSession,
                        didChangeTo toState: HKWorkoutSessionState,
                        from fromState: HKWorkoutSessionState,
                        date: Date)
```

Apple's widget button doesn't trigger either of these methods.

Question: How do I listen for the play/pause button? Alternatively, can I turn this widget off for my app, given that I'm implementing my own stack widget?

Note: My own widget using the .onOpenURL works as desired, as does my usage of the HKWorkoutSessionDelegate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might try this solution, I did and it solves the problem:

```
    func workoutSession(_ workoutSession: HKWorkoutSession, didGenerate event: HKWorkoutEvent) {
        if(event.type == HKWorkoutEventType.pauseOrResumeRequest) {
            if self.running { // HKWorkoutSessionState is 'running'
                pauseWorkout()
            }
            else {
                resumeWorkout()
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope it helps!